# Which of the following sets are subspaces of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be a vector space and let U, W, X $\subset$ V be sub-vector spaces of V.

Which of the following sets are again subspaces of V?

a) U $\triangle$ W

b) U $\cap$ W

c) U $\cup$ W

d) v + U for a v $\in$ V

*So a subspace of a Vector V is a subset U that satisfies three Axioms(Conditions):

(UV0) The zero Vector is in U

(UV1) U is closed under addition

(UV2) U is closed under multipication of scalars*

-For a) I don`t know how to prove if it is a vector subspace of V or not! Need some help

-For b) I have proved this way but I´m not sure: We have to check if the three Axioms are satisfied:

(UV0): Is 0 $\in$ U and 0 $\in$ W, and because that both of them are subspaces $\Rightarrow$ 0 $\in$ U $\cap$ W $\Rightarrow$ U $\cap$ W $\neq$ $\varnothing$

(UV1): Let u,v $\in$ U $\cap$ W, and because that U and W are subspaces, follows:
(u,v $\in$ U $\Rightarrow$ u+v $\in$ U) and (u,v $\in$ W $\Rightarrow$ u+v $\in$ W) $\Rightarrow$ u+v $\in$ U $\cap$ W

(UV2): Let u $\in$ U $\cap$ W and $\lambda \in$ K $\Rightarrow$ (u $\in$ U, $\lambda$ $\in$ K $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda$u $\in$ U ) and (u $\in$ W, $\lambda$ $\in$ K $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda$u $\in$ W )
$\Rightarrow$ $\lambda$u $\in$ U $\cap$ W.

-For c) I need an Idea aswell and

-For d) I think it should be proved with to cases 1.Fall v $\notin$ U and 2.Fall v$\in$U, I´m not sure if this is the right Idea and if it is how to prove it

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your ideas are right. The proof is right. Adapt it to prove that $v+U$ is a subspace when $v \in U$. Can $0 \in v+U$ if $v \notin U$?

For union think of lines in the plane for a counterexample.

For $U \Delta V$, can $0$ be in it?

**Proof for $v+U$.** If $v \notin U$, then suppose for a contradiction that $v+U$ is a subspace. Then $0 \in v+U$ i.e. there is an $u \in U$ such that $0 = v + u$. But then $v=-u \in U$, which is a contradiction.

If $v \in U$, then $\forall u \in U$, we have that $v+u \in U$. So $v+U \subseteq U$. Moreover, $\forall u \in U$ we have $(-v)+u \in U$, so $u = v + (-v) + u \in v + U$. Hence, also $U \subseteq v + U$.

By double inclusion, $v + U = U$, and thus is a subspace.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Hi, if you´re here, can you help me a little bit more with v+U task, I understood the other ones clearly, but this one not

Comment: Added to the proof for clarification.

Comment: thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2):

Proposition: $\;U\cup V\;$ is a vectorial subspace iff $\;U\subset V\;$ or $\;V\subset U\;$

Hint for the proof: Direction $\;\Longleftarrow\;$ is trivial. For the other diection, suppose that both $\;U\not\subset V\;$ and also $\;V\not\subset U\;$ . Then there exists $\;u\in U\setminus V\;$ nad $\;v\in V\setminus U\;$ ...well, your turn

Comment: Thanks for the propositon, but for which one of the tasks is that

Comment: Did you mean $U \cup V$ instead of $U+V$? The sum of two subspaces is always a subspace.

Comment: @azif00 Of course. Good catch, thanks.